# What is "next-size-adjust" in meta tag?

Tags: html, next.js, meta-tags

Hello I work in an app with next js and I see next-size-adjust in meta tag. I would like to know what is this.

This is my source code (head):

```
<head>
    <meta name="next-size-adjust" />
</head>
```

I make a W3c validation test and I have this error "Element meta is missing one or more of the following attributes: content, property."

So I put the content attribute but I don't know if it's good :

```
head>
    <meta name="next-size-adjust" content="100%" />
</head>
```

Comment: I can't find much on the internet, apart from [this discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/62126), which has no answers as well unfortunately

Answer (score -1):

The next-size-adjust meta tag is a special meta tag used by Next.js to help improve the performance of your application by adjusting the size of the viewport when certain elements are loaded. This can help to reduce layout shifts and improve the user experience. As such, it may not be supported by all web browsers.

Comment: Source? This seems you just copied this from somewhere